# Request always get RequestTimeoutException

Tags: request, timeout, masstransit

I am using ASP.NET Core + Simple Injector and MassTransit v5.1.5. Each time I try to use Request/Response I get a RequestTimeoutException.

```
{
            var host = c.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });

            c.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test_sample_injector", ep =>
            {
                // the prefetch count is important for the performance
                ep.PrefetchCount = 16;

                // ep.LoadFrom requires the service provider which should be build on the top of services
                // and would load all implementations of IConsumer<T> that were added as scoped above
                ep.LoadFrom(container);

                // the endpoint needs to be binded to a class/interface otherwise the messages are going into
                // _skipped queue
                ep.Bind<SampleMessage>();

                EndpointConvention.Map<SampleMessage>(ep.InputAddress);

                ep.Handler<IMessage>(context =>
                {
                    // the handler is called before the consumer
                    return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: from handler!");
                });
            });
        };
```

This is the RabbitMQ config I use. I have the following container registration of consumer:

```
        container.Register<IConsumer<SampleMessage>, SampleMessageConsumer>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

And the consumer looks like:

```
  public class SampleMessageConsumer : IConsumer<SampleMessage>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SampleMessage> context)
    {
        await context.RespondAsync<DoneSampleMessage>(
            new DoneSampleMessage
            {
                Result = context.Message.Text.ToUpperInvariant()
            });
    }
}
```

The call I make is:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get()
        {
            var r = await _msgSender.Request<SampleMessage, DoneSampleMessage>(
                new SampleMessage() { Text = "[Simple Injector]Hello World!" });


            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

All the handlers and consumers are called but the RespondAsync seems like it's not working. I have a MessageSender where I have the Request method:

```
 public Task<TResponse> Request<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest r)
        where TRequest : class
        where TResponse : class
    {
        var client = new MessageRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(
            MessageBus,
            _serviceAddress,
            _timeout);

        return client.Request(r);
    }
```

I have started the Bus as well.

So any ideas where to look for the reason of this RequestTimeoutException or at least how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Skipped queue is usually a type issue but you said your consumer is called, so that doesn’t make sense. Bind shouldn’t be necessary.

Comment: I see that the endpoint configuration has been called several times. I think the issue is because same endpoint has been registered several times. Therefore there is same consumer registered several times.... But that is just a guess. I would bet I have problem in the use of Simple Injector, but I still don't know where to look for it.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson we have solved the problem! The BusRegistration was not marked as Singleton and therefore the endpoint configuration was called several times.